# ¿Como saber que archivos tengo dentro de mi ArrayList en java?

Tags: java

tengo un `ArrayList<String>` el cual amaceno archivos con extensiones **.pnd .ana .cnf** con sus respectivos nombres. Lo que necesito saber es como preguntar si dentro del ArrayList existen esas tres extensiones, **solamente las extensiones** y **NO** el nombre de archivo completo con su respectiva extensión, por ej: si se encuentra las extensiones **.pnd** y **.ana** que no haga nada, si se encuentra **.pnd** y **.cnf** que tampoco haga nada **pero si dentro del array se encuentran archivos solamente de extension .pnd recien hay que realice una acción**, me explico? Hasta ahora e echo lo siguiente:

```
private void evaluarArchivos() {

        String pnd = ".pnd";
        String ana = ".ana";
        String cnf = ".cnf";
        private boolean archivoExistente = true;

        for (String evaluar : arrayArchivos) {
            if (evaluar.contains(pnd) || evaluar.contains(ana)) {
                archivoExistente = false;
                System.out.println("Nada");
            } 
            if (evaluar.contains(pnd) || evaluar.contains(cnf)) {
                archivoExistente = false;
                System.out.println("Nada 2");
            }
            if (evaluar.contains(pnd)) {
                archivoExistente = true;
                System.out.println("Hacer algo");
            }
        }
    }
```

Utilizo la propiedad `contains` pero siempre me devuelve `true` ya que las tres extensiones se encuentran dentro del arraylist siempre, y por cada vuelta que da mi metodo buscarArchivos se ingrementa lo que tenia mas lo que se agrega nuevo.

```
 public void buscarArchivo(File ruta) {
//        Creo el vector que contendra todos los archivos de una ruta especificada.
        File[] archivo = ruta.listFiles();
//        Evaluo si la carpeta especificada contiene archivos.
        if (archivo != null) {
//            Recorro el vector el cual tiene almacenado la ruta del archivo a buscar.
            for (int i = 0; i < archivo.length; i++) {
                File Arc = archivo[i];
//                Evaluo si el archivo o la ruta es una carpeta.
                if (archivo[i].isDirectory()) {
//                    Le paso la nueva ruta de la carpeta si se cambia la ruta e busca nuevamente.
                    buscarArchivo(archivo[i]);
                } else {
//                    Evaluo el tipo de extencion. 
                    if (archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".pnd") || archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".ana") || archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".cnf")) {
                        contador++;
                        arrayArchivos.add(archivo[i].getName());

//                        System.out.println("Lo que hay en el array es: " + arrayArchivos);
                        evaluarArchivos();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Pienso que tal vez me da `true` porque en cada vuelta de mi bugle de mi método **buscarArchivo** agrega constantemente nuevos archivos dejando los viejos que a buscados en la vuelta anterior, como podría evitar eso? Seria que por cada vuelta que de el bugle me agregue al array, lo evalué y que lo elimine, en la siguiente vuelta que haga lo mismo y así sucesivamente. **Tener solamente en el array los archivos que se encuentran en cada vuelta que da y no los anteriores**. Nose si me hago entender...

Otra solucion que pense es hacer un if dentro del bugle evaluando si no todas las extensiones terminan con .pnd poniendo mi variable `archivoExistente = false`

```
                     if (archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".pnd") || archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".ana") || archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".cnf")) {
                        if(!archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".pnd")){
                            // Si no termina con .pnd implica que no todos los archivos son de esa extensión
                             archivoExistente = false;
                             System.out.println("Nada");
                        }
                        contador++;
                        arrayArchivos.add(archivo[i].getName());
                    }
```

Pero no me funciona porque me agrega solamente extensiones de tipo .pnd y lo que necesito **es evaluar el tipo de archivos que hay dentro de la carpeta antes de agregarlo o agregar todos los archivos que se encuentran dentro de la carpeta y luego evaluar que tipo de extensión son**. Espero que me puedan ayudar. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso del metodo [.split(".")](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) que tiene la clase String, esta te va a devolver un array de tokens donde deberas sacar el ultimo elemento del arreglo para saber cual tipo de archivo es, para verificar que solamente se ejecute un cierto código cuando solo existan archivos .pnd, puedes utilizar banderas quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
private void evaluarArchivos(List arrayArchivos) {
    boolean existePnd = false,
            existeAna = false,
            existeCnf = false;

    for (String archivo : arrayArchivos) {
        String [] palabras = archivo.split(".");
        String ext = palabras[palabras.length() - 1];

        if (ext.equals("pnd"))
            existePnd = true;

        if (ext.equals("ana"))
            existeAna = true;

        if (ext.equals("cnf"))
            existeCnf = true;
    }
    if(existePnd && (!existeAna && !existeCnf)){
        //Codigo si solo existen archivos .pnd
    }
}
```

Comment: @z1IV3r gracias por tu ayuda, me fue muy útil realmente! Pero investigando un poquito, leyendo acá y aya encontré un error en tu código, siempre me daba la excepción **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1** lo cual me llevaba a la linea `String ext = palabras[palabras.length - 1];` SEGÚN lo que e leído era porque en la linea `String[] palabras = archivo.split(".");` de tu código suministrado en la respuesta, el método **split(".")** si se utiliza el punto debe llevar los caracteres **\\**  quedando así **String[] palabras = archivo.split("\\.");**

Comment: Ya que el punto se usa en las expresiones regulares por lo que si se desea usar como tal se debe definir con "\\" después de varios intentos logre hacer una parte de lo que necesitaba, mi problema ahora lo tengo en el **ArrayList**, debo buscar la forma de vaciarlo en cada vuelta que de porque sino siempre me quedaran archivos viejos y las condiciones brindadas en la respuesta no se cumplen debido a que en la carpeta donde se buscan los archivos se agregan y se eliminan constantemente las extensiones. Igualmente tu respuesta es valida, la doy como valida. Saludos

Comment: Perfecto estimado, tendré en cuenta lo que comentas para futuras cuestiones, me alegra que te ayudó.

Answer (score 1):

Usando `streams` de `Java 8` se simplifica mucho:

```
long numeroExtensionesDiferentes = lista.stream()//se crea un stream
                .map(item->item.substring(item.lastIndexOf(".")+1))//quitamos la parte anterior a la extensión
                .distinct()//se eliminan los elementos(extensiones) duplicados
                .count();//se cuenta el número de elementos (extensiones)
```

Comment: El código falla con un falso positivo como `troll.pdf.enganiado`

Comment: Se ajusta al ejemplo que daba. Para lógicas más complejas habría que cambiar la parte del substring por otro código más apropiado, pero entiendo que no es lo que preguntaba.

Comment: O puedes cambiar `indexOf` por `lastIndexOf` y listo.

Answer (score 1):

@Gerardo Ferreyra, creo que siempre da `true` por el último `if` que tienes,

```
if (evaluar.contains(pnd)) {
            archivoExistente = true;
            System.out.println("Hacer algo");
        }
```

En este `if` preguntas si existen archivos con extensión ".pnd" pero no si son los únicos que existen, para lo cual debes adicionar las condicionales de que las demás extensiones no existan:

```
if (evaluar.contains(pnd) && !evaluar.contains(ana) && !evaluar.contains(cnf)) {
            archivoExistente = true;
            System.out.println("Hacer algo");
        }
```